I tried to draw a red rectangle in Pygame, but the screen is black
This is my pygame code:
import pygame as pg

pg.init()

W, H = 500, 400
screen = pg.display.set_mode((W, H))
run = True
rect = pg.Rect(50, 50, 60, 60)
screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
pg.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), rect)

while run:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            run = False

pg.display.flip()
pg.quit()

But I get this error:
Exception has occurred: ValueError invalid rectstyle
object File "myfolder/myfile.py", line 9, in screen.fill(0,0,0)
ValueError: invalid rectstyle object

I've tried:
screen.fill((0,0,0)) pg.draw.rect(screen, ((255,0,0)), rect)

Which fixed the error but the screen is still black
Why is the screen still black?

Welcome to Stack Overflow,  please read How to Ask for tips on how to write a good question.  Your title should better sum up the specific problem you're facing so future users facing similar issues can find this question.  Also some more context to your problem would be useful

What happens if you move pg.display.flip() before the while run loop?

while run:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            run = False

    pg.display.flip() # indent this inside loop so that screen can update

Another way is, instead of using pg.display.flip() you can use pg.display.update method

This function is like an optimized version of pygame.display.flip() for software displays. It allows only a portion of the screen to be updated, instead of the entire area. If no argument is passed it updates the entire Surface area like pygame.display.flip().

Credit to @AryaanSheth, to pointing that out

I would prefer to use pg.display.update() as it provides more functionality such as being able to update only a part of the screen should the need arise. You can find it documented here

@AryaanSheth I know, I didn't change it to updated because OP has in his question.

... change it to it to update() function .... CORRECTION
